# Has my understanding of a generating set been wrong this entire time?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

My understanding of the generating set (informally) was the following

> Pick any number of elements, say $g_1, g_2, \dotso, g_n$, in a finite group $G$. The set of all elements produced by a finite product of any combination of these elements is called the *generating set* of the elements $g_1, g_2, \dotso, g_n$.

However, the course notes had the following definition of a generating set.

> If $S \subseteq$ G is a subset, then define $S^{-1} =  \left ( s^{-1} | s \in S  \right )$ and let $\langle S \rangle$ denote the set of all elements  of $G$ which can be written as finite products of elements of $S \bigcup S^{-1}.$

Am I missing something in my understanding of the generating set? Because in my understanding of it, there's absolutely nothing to do with any inverse elements whereas the course notes makes some mention of them for some reason.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The book definition works with infinite groups, too. In the finite case, if you have $g$, then $g^{-1}=g^{|G|-1}$, so you don't need to specifically add inverses to the generation process.

Answer (score 20):

Firstly you seem to have confused two things a "generating set" and the "subgroup generated by". In my opinion the correct definition of each is as follows: A subset $S$ of a group $G$ is a **generating set** of $G$ if for any subgroup $H$ of $G$ if $S \subseteq H$ then $H=G$. While if $S$ is a subset of a group $G$, the **subgroup generated** by $S$, often denoted $\langle S\rangle$, is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$.

The two concepts are related of course. A subset $S$ is a generating set for $G$ if and only if the subgroup generated by $S$ is $G$.

Finally one might be interested in constructing the subgroup generated by $S$. Trivially $\langle S\rangle = \cap\{H|S\subseteq H \leq G\}$. If one prefers one can build it inductively $S_0=\{e\}\cup S$, $S_n = \{x^{-1}y\,|\,x,y \in S_{n-1}\} \cup S_{n-1}$, then $\langle S \rangle = \cup \{S_i|i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ or one of many other equivalent ways. However as mentioned in the answer by Thomas Andrews above when $G$ is finite one can simply take $S_0=S$, $S_n=\{xy\,|\,x\in S,y\in S_{n-1}\}\cup S_{n-1}$ and then $\langle S\rangle = S_{|G|}$ corresponding to what you described above.

Comment: Good call spotting the fogginess of the poster around "subgroup generated by" and "generating set."

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example to show you why it matters to include inverses of elements of $S$ when describing the generated subgroup.

If you took $(\Bbb Z,+)$ and take $S=\{1\}$, the set of finite products (read *sums* since the operation is written additively) would only get you $\Bbb N$. (You would still get $0$ as an empty sum of $1$'s.)

When you only use the elements of $S$ and the operation to generate a subset of a subgroup, you are only guaranteed to get the [*monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) generated by $S$. You've got to throw in inverses in order to get the rest.

Comment: This is a great and very easy-to-understand example. Thanks.